# How to save the result of a @escaping closure function into a variable?

Tags: swift, callback, closures

I currently have a class which is below:

```
class Anton {

    //URL to web service (Internal)
    let URL_DISPLAY_MENU = "http://192.168.1.100/api/DisplayMenu.php"

    func displayMenu(completion: @escaping ([[String:Any]]) ->()) {
        let requestURL = URL(string: URL_DISPLAY_MENU)
        var request = URLRequest(url: requestURL!)
        request.httpMethod = "POST"
        var menu: [[String:Any]]?


        let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { data,response,error in guard let data = data, error == nil else {
            print("error=\(String(describing: error))")
            return
            }
            do {
                if let httpStatus = response as? HTTPURLResponse, httpStatus.statusCode != 200 {
                    print("statusCode should be 200, but is \(httpStatus.statusCode)")
                    print("response = \(String(describing: response))")
                } else {
                    menu = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: []) as? [[String: Any]] ?? []
                    var dictionary = [Int:Any]()
                    for (index,item) in menu!.enumerated() {
                        let uniqueID = index
                        dictionary[uniqueID] = item
                    }
                    completion(menu!)
                }
            } catch let error as NSError {
                print(error)
            }

        }
        task.resume()
    }
}
```

At the moment I use the class & contained function as follows:

```
var anton = Anton()

anton.displayMenu { menu in
            print(menu)
}
```

What I want to do is have a way of saving the @escaping result into a global variable.  I'm very new to escaping closures so not sure how to go about this.

Comment: But @escaping ([[String:Any]]) ->() doesn't have a result. ->() indicates that it is void. What result do you mean exactly?

Comment: Ah, I guess I've made a mistake with my function, What I want essentially is, from that function within the class Anton, I want to return the menu variable.  I then want to save that variable globally when I call the function elsewhere within another class.

Answer (score 0):

You can save your value directly in completion.

Example:

```
var anton = Anton()

anton.displayMenu { menu in
    self.myMenu = menu
}
```